# Web page[Gmail]: content does not match page source

Tags: javascript, html, gmail

Just for curiosity, was just going through the page source of gmail inbox:
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox and in the view, we see items such as Inbox, Starred, Drafts etc. but when I tried searching for those terms in the page source, they didn't show up. 
I also could not find any ajax functions that dynamically updates the content.

Can anyone help shed light on why the code doesn't match the view? Or are they just going to great lengths to obfuscate the code?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe "Elements" tab in devtools can help you. Anyway, this question is really off-topic here

Comment: I often wondered how google renders their pages. Looking through their page source depresses my confidence of web development

Comment: @k102 I'm not trying to do anything other than understand their code. As for off-topic, maybe you can tell me what tags are better for this question? Also, "Elements" tab does not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding The Page Sources in Facebook and Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114561/understanding-the-page-sources-in-facebook-and-gmail)

Comment: Hmm seems my question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114561/understanding-the-page-sources-in-facebook-and-gmail

So I guess they do obfuscate the code. I wonder if the tools they use for that are open source?